# javascript ( while loop )

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, while-loop

hi everyone am fairly new to javascript , so i wrote this fizzbuzz challenge but somehow it wouldn't run i don't know what to do , thanks and here's the code :

```
var output = []
var count =1;

function fizzBuzz(){
  while(count<=100){
    if (count%3===0 && count%5===0){
     output.push("fizzbuzz");
    }else if (count%3===0){
      output.push("fizz");
    }else if (count%5===0){
      output.push("buzz");
    }else {
      output.push(count);
    }
    count++;
  }
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: What do you mean **wouldn't run**

Comment: I get `[1, 2, 'fizz', 4, 'buzz', 'fizz', 7, 8, 'fizz', 'buzz', 11, 'fizz', 13, 14, 'fizzbuzz', 16, 17, 'fizz', 19, 'buzz', 'fizz', 22, 23, 'fizz', 'buzz', 26, 'fizz', 28, 29, 'fizzbuzz', 31, 32, 'fizz', 34, 'buzz', 'fizz', 37, 38, 'fizz', 'buzz', 41, 'fizz', 43, 44, 'fizzbuzz', 46, 47, 'fizz', 49, 'buzz', 'fizz', 52, 53, 'fizz', 'buzz', 56, 'fizz', 58, 59, 'fizzbuzz', 61, 62, 'fizz', 64, 'buzz', 'fizz', 67, 68, 'fizz', 'buzz', 71, 'fizz', 73, 74, 'fizzbuzz', 76, 77, 'fizz', 79, 'buzz', 'fizz', 82, 83, 'fizz', 'buzz', 86, 'fizz', 88, 89, 'fizzbuzz', 91, ...`

Comment: `92, 'fizz', 94, 'buzz', 'fizz', 97, 98, 'fizz', 'buzz']`

Comment: i didin't call the function lol .

Answer (score 1):

i would have used a for loop there, even tho that would work fine, you didnt call the function. add `fizzBuzz();` at the bottom

Comment: omg ! i must be very dumb for not knowing that xD 
am using firefox debugger so i though if i only click on execute it will call the function directly ... 
thank you .
but i didn't get what you mean by " i would have used a loop there " am fairly new sorry ^^

Comment: hehe all good, we have all been there, and by saying i would have used a for loop i mean i will not use the while loop, i would have used this:

Answer (score 1):

```js
var output = [];

function fizzBuzz(){
  for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    if (i%3===0 && i%5===0){
     output.push("fizzbuzz");
    }else if (i%3===0){
      output.push("fizz");
    }else if (i%5===0){
      output.push("buzz");
    }else {
      output.push(i);
    }
    console.log(output);
  }
}

fizzBuzz();
```

for the while loop

that way you dont need a count variable and its much cleaner

Comment: oh , i see now , yeah it's much cleaner , thak you very much ^^ .